# JSON Decodable - search by key

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

I am trying to do a little code to get information from my JSON through a key.

The JSON looks like:

```
{
  "Test Name": {
    "schede": {
      "info_01": "Info 01",
      "info_02": "Info 02",
      "info_03": "Info 03",
      "info_04": "Info 04",
      "info_05": "Info 05"
      },
    "Info" : "info"
  }
}
```

I want that JSON is downloaded at the start of app.
JSON is decoded and I want to create a function that passing a key it will print all information that I need like
schede.info_01 or info string that is on JSON.
It’s like a decodable JSON

The key in my JSON for example is: “Test Name”
Then if you pass in the function the string ‘Test Name’ it will print each result like: “Test Name”.schede.info_01 etc

I am getting the JSON from a link

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Decodable` for this purpose? Just transforming the JSON using `JSONSerialization` into a Dictionary would be way easier to use for such a function.

Comment: I need to get single information from the key and not directly the whole json

Comment: I mean to say that transforming the JSON into a Dictionary (using JSONSerialization)  instead of a struct/class (using Decodable) would give you much more flexibility in writing a function which would allow you to print the data in the manner you want.

Comment: Also, for the purposes of clarity could you expand upon the expected output and write a complete example

Comment: Are this part of json , can you update your question with all response to know if you have array fo Dictionary

Comment: I think that I will follow ZeMoon idea but I don’t know how do at the moment

Answer (score 2):

First create your data model from the json:

```
struct MyData: Codable {
    let testName: TestName

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case testName = "Test Name"
    }
}

struct TestName: Codable {
    let schede: [String: String]
    let info: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case schede
        case info = "Info"
    }
}
```

If you're not sure your JSON will always have a particular value, you can  make a property optional.

then create a function which will fetch data and parse it:

```
func getData(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: MyData?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let receivedData = data else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        do {
            // Check if there is a valid json object and parse it with JSONDecoder
            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyData.self, from: receivedData)
            completion(object, nil)
        } catch {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And call your function:

```
    getData(url: URL(string: "https://yourexampleurl.com/myData")!) { (data, error) in
        // if you want to use the received data in the UI
        // you need to dispatch it back to the main thread
        // because dataTask executes it not on the main thread (by default)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let info1 = data?.testName.schede["info_01"] {
                print("received mt info: \(info1)")
            } else {
                let errorMessage = error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error"
                print("error occured: \(errorMessage)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Because you mapped json structure to Swift objects you can access your data with the dot operator:

```
let info1 = data.testName.schede["info_01"]
```

You could go all the way and create model for `Schede` object too, then instead of parsing it as a dictionary you could access values something like this:

```
let info1 = data.testName.schede.info1
```

Comment: Please, when using `Codable` declare the properties in the custom structs as much as possible **non**-optional – in most cases you know what the server is going to send – and handle the (design) errors in the `catch` block. `try?` with `JSONDecoder` is very bad.

Comment: @vadian I edited my answer. I totally agree with the `do` `catch` point. Regarding optionals in the model, I agree with the "as much as possible" point.

Comment: I have done in this way too but I need that the json is downloaded only one time and I can call function of get result by key in all files

Comment: If you need to download the data only one time, then do just that - call the function once, store the retrieved data and make it accessible to other objects.